# Entirety of stack being set to one value

Tags: java, android, stack

I have a rather perplexing problem. I am programming for Android and I am trying to get the combinations of a set of integers. I have written out the code to generate the combos, and I track it with the remote debugger and it seems to be working correctly. It works by putting each new combo in a stack. However, every combo in the stack is being updated with each change of the active array that is being altered and committed to the stack repeatedly in multiple forms. I believe the problem relates to my new combos containing pointers to the original array rather than copies of the array's contents at the time of the combo's creation. However, I am not sure how to fix the problem.

All advice is appreciated, and thank you for your time.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param comboSize
 *            The desired size of combo
 * @param values
 *            The dataset we are finding the values of; must be ints
 * @return an array containing all possible combos of comboSize for values
 */
private Combo[] getCombos(int comboSize, int[] values) {

    Stack<Combo> combos = new Stack<Combo>();
    // combos.ensureCapacity((int) Math.pow(values.length, comboSize) + 1);

    getIntArrayZeroToTarget(values.length - 1);

    int[] temp = getIntArrayZeroToTarget(comboSize-1);
    // System.arraycopy(surrogates, 0, temp, 0, comboSize);

    combos.push(new Combo(temp));

    // int workIndex = comboSize-1;

    //Evil things lurked in this code. Two days evaporated during mortal combat with it. I surrendered.

    switch (comboSize){
        case 2: for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j < values.length; j++){
                temp[0] = i;
                temp[1] = j;
                combos.push(new Combo(temp));
            }
        } break;
        case 3: for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j < values.length; j++){
                for (int k = j+1; k < values.length; k++){
                    temp[0] = i;
                    temp[1] = j;
                    temp[2] = k;
                    combos.push(new Combo(temp));
                }
            }
        } break;        
        case 4: for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j < values.length; j++){
                for (int k = j+1; k < values.length; k++){
                    for (int l = k+1; l < values.length; l++){
                        temp[0] = i;
                        temp[1] = j;
                        temp[2] = k;
                        temp[3] = l;
                        combos.push(new Combo(temp));                   
                    }
                }
            }
        } break;
    }

    //This code converts the psudoCombos (which contain the indices of the values) to combos that contain the actual values from the user
    Stack<Combo> cCombos = new Stack<Combo>();

    while (!combos.isEmpty()) {
        int[] temp1 = combos.pop().getContents();
        int[] temp2 = new int[temp1.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp1.length; i++)
            temp2[i] = values[temp1[i]];

        cCombos.push(new Combo(temp2));

    }

    Combo[] aCombos = new Combo[cCombos.size()];

    for (int i = 0; !cCombos.isEmpty(); i++){ //I spent about 7 hours debugging this code because I was missing the c in cCombos here...
        aCombos[i] = cCombos.pop();

    }
    String[] tempS = new String[aCombos.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < aCombos.length; i++){
        tempS[i] = aCombos[i].toString();
    }

    combosAsStrings = tempS;

    return aCombos;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in saying that your problem comes from Combo objects referencing the same array. To fix this, simply allocate a new array before each Combo object you create. So in each inner for loop of the switch statement, put this line first:

```
temp = new int[comboSize];
```

That should fix your problem. (Alternatively, you can have the default constructor of Combo simply create a new array and copy the array that was given to it into the new one.)

**So** there's your problem, but here are some suggestions:

**First:** The "two-stage" approach to solving this problem can be consolidated into one if you just reference the values[] array in the inner for loops of the switch statement. For example, in the first for loop, under case 2, replace the relevant lines with:

```
temp[0] = values[i];
temp[1] = values[j];
```

then push the combo. This gets rid of the need to do a "second pass" going from pseudo-combos to real ones, AND eliminates the need for the third aCombos loop, which I assume you are using to simply get back to the original order of the combos (since the second pass loop reverses it.)

**Second:** You could eliminate the need for a switch/case statement and repetitive code by using a recursive function. This is outside the scope of the question, but it would also allow you to support combinations of any number of values, not just the numbers that you hardcode (currently up to four.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I started writing an arbitrary combination size method but stopped when I realized the project only required 2-4 and significantly less thinking would be involved writing the method for a fixed combo size.